# ffmpeg: preserve transparency when scaling png

Tags: ffmpeg, png

I'm trying to invoke the following command:

```
ffmpeg -y -i 1.png -vf "thumbnail=300,scale='min(300,iw)':-1" -frames:v 1 o.png
```

Input file:

[image]

Output file:

[image]

Is it possible to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the [thumbnail](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#thumbnail) filter. It does not preserve transparency and it does nothing in your command as it is intended to be used with a video input and not a single image input:

> thumbnail
>   Select the most representative frame in a given sequence of
>   consecutive frames.

```
ffmpeg -y -i 1.png -vf "scale='min(300,iw)':-1" -frames:v 1 o.png
```

You can view the source code of `libavfilter/vf_thumbnail.c` to see supported pixel formats:

```
static const enum AVPixelFormat pix_fmts[] = {
    AV_PIX_FMT_RGB24, AV_PIX_FMT_BGR24,
    AV_PIX_FMT_NONE
};
```

None of these support transparency (it would contain `A` in the pixel format name that does support transparency/alpha).